# Solr indexing short hyphenated words with numbers

Tags: solr

I have searched stack overflow for this question but none address the specific pattern letter-hyphen-number which seems to be a specific case Solr has trouble with.

We have products with short hyphenated alphanumeric words that need to be indexed in Solr and be searchable.  For example a product titled "aimpoint t-2".  User's should be able to query "t-2" or "aimpoint t-2" to get a result.

I have tried every possible tokenizer and filter combination and cannot accomplish this, hopefully it's something simple I missed.

Relevant section of schema.xml (Solr 6.5):

```
<field name="product_name" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />

<fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.ClassicTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory" preserveOriginal="1"/>
            <filter class="solr.FlattenGraphFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.ClassicTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory" preserveOriginal="1"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

Thanks in advance

UPDATE 1:

Per MatsLindh answer I have the following updated schema.xml

```
<fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

Here is the output of the analysis tab:
[image]

And here is the debug query data:

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jordotech/d73fecfe6e6c0ee8c2177ea2bd9d5ff2/raw/6969686eef7a43f2072849138a7178b41692e6a8/query_debug.json

Could it have something to do with this portion of the debug json?

```
"parsedquery":"+(+SynonymQuery(Synonym(text:t text:t2)) +text:2)",
    "parsedquery_toString":"+(+Synonym(text:t text:t2) +text:2)",
```

Seems to be stripping out the hyphen

Comment: I figured it out, my changes were having no effect on the results because of this line in schema.xml `<defaultSearchField>text</defaultSearchField>` which actually corresponds to the description of the product in my case.  This thing was misconfigured to begin with, while product titles were being indexed, they were not searchable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solr does not have any special issues about `-` in the indexing process - any processing will be determined by the rules from the tokenizers and filters, and you can use the `Analysis` tab in the Solr admin interface to see exactly how your text is processed through each step in your chain.

You're going to need a `WhitespaceTokenizer` to only split on  (and not `-` which the `StandardTokenizer` or `ClassicTokenizer` will split on. The Classic Tokenizer *should* leave `t-2` alone, but your next steps will not).

You'll also going to drop the `WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory` unless you want to split it further (i.e. if you need to support searching for just `t` and not only `t-2`.

From the description of the word delimiter graph filter:

> Non-alphanumeric characters (discarded): "hot-spot" -> "hot", "spot"

.. which is not what you want if you want to keep the token as `t-2`.

Comment: I updated the post after your suggestions, take a look if you can

Comment: I made these changes and get the same result, turns out any "x-x" pattern is not searchable whether they're integers or strings or a combination

Comment: I figured it out, my changes were having no effect on the results because of this line in schema.xml `<defaultSearchField>text</defaultSearchField>` which actually corresponds to the description of the product.